# java.io.IOException when running 'grails tomcat deploy'

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I'm trying to deploy a Grails app via the tomcat plugin by running `grails tomcat deploy`. It works perfectly fine when doing it this way, except that all of my configuration in the WAR file are their development values (the development datasource is trying to be used from my deployed WAR file, for example).

I then attempt to run `grails prod tomcat deploy`, and the following error occurs:

```
| Done creating WAR target/app##0.1-build-004.war
Deploying application /app to Tomcat
| Error Error executing script Tomcat: : java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:267)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask.execute(DeployTask.java:195)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:141)
        at Tomcat$_run_closure1.doCall(Tomcat:31)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:220)
        ... 24 more
| Error Error executing script Tomcat: : java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening? I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and Java 7u71.

Comment: If you [google that error message quoted](https://www.google.com/search?q="Error+writing+request+body+to+server"+tomcat) you get lots of hits

Comment: I took a look at the resolutions to those (when there was a resolution) but none seem to resolve the issue here.

Comment: If changing the environment causes the deploy to fail, is it possible that this is a bug?

Comment: Hey Casey Hope all is well, found this and it might be of use: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/1-2-M4-Remote-deploying-to-Tomcat-td1345406.html

Answer (score 0):

For tomcat 7+ you need to add the manager-script role to your user in tomcat-users.xml.

from [Grails Tomcat Plugin Docs](http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat):

Tomcat 7
If you are using Tomcat 7, ensure the user has the manager-script role

```
<user username="manager" password="secret" roles="manager-script" />
```

Comment: I do have the manager-script role, which was required for me to get this working in the first place. The problem is that the deploy doesn't work when the environment is set to production.

Comment: can you post what you have in the config.groovy?